# Should we get rid of all the tags that were used only just a few times?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/545887/tags-popularity) shows that we have **lots** of tags that were used only once, twice, or just a few times. Such tags are easy to burinate and re-tagging should not flood the main page if it would not be done at once. Maybe it's a good idea..?

Comment: Apart from misspellings that are synonyms of other tags, how would we determine which ones have no value?  How would we distinguish those that might grow in use from those that will never be used again? What is the problem with rare tags, anyway?

Comment: @whuber those are the questions that I (implicitly) wanted to rise. Finding the rare ones would be an easy (while naive) method for finding the "strange" tags.

Comment: I still don't see why there's any problem that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @whuber that the fact, *in isolation*, that a tag has only ever been used a few times is not necessarily an indication of any problems.  It does seem reasonable to me that rarely-ever-used-ness correlates with other properties of tags that may indicate some issues that should be addressed.  What I take from these facts is that each tag that might be a candidate for being made a synonym or for burnination should be investigated.  If a reason other than low frequency is discovered, that tag could be nominated and the case for action could be made.

As an aside, be aware that tags that are only on a single thread are silently discarded by the SE system after a period of time.  (I think it's 6 months, but I'd have to look it up.)

Comment: Agreed. If I search for something, the fact that a tag has been used rarely is part of the results. I really don't want a search on tags to reveal nothing unless the tag has not been used. Zoos don't get rid of single specimens as a matter of principle....